# jasmine karma unit test "Error: Unexpected request: GET /Content/json/3420_layer0.json"

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, karma-jasmine, httpbackend

Writing a simple test case.

```
describe('Services', function () {

    describe('API', function () {

        var $httpBackend, $rootScope, createController, requestHandler;
        var jsonLayer0 = "/Content/json/3420_layer0.json";

        // Set up the module
        beforeEach(module('anbud'));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
            // Set up the mock http service responses
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

            $httpBackend.whenGET(jsonLayer0).respond(200, '');

            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

            // The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
            var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

            createController = function () {
                return $controller('anbudTreeController', { '$scope': $rootScope });
            };
        }));

        afterEach(function () {
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });

        it('should fetch first layer', function () {
            $httpBackend.expectGET(jsonLayer0);
            var controller = createController();
            $rootScope.getFirstLayer();
            $httpBackend.flush();
        });
```

I get:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /Content/json/3420_layer0.json
```

But, I do have:

```
var jsonLayer0 = "/Content/json/3420_layer0.json";
$httpBackend.whenGET(jsonLayer0).respond(200, '');
```

So, not sure what the problem is...

Full stack trace:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET test
        No more request expected
            at $httpBackend (C:/git/angularjs/NSview/NSviewer/Scripts/angular-mocks.js:1244:9)
            at $httpBackend (C:/git/angularjs/NSview/NSviewer/Scripts/angular-mocks.js:1237:11)
            at sendReq (C:/git/angularjs/NSview/NSviewer/Scripts/angular.js:10515:9)
            at serverRequest (C:/git/angularjs/NSview/NSviewer/Scripts/angular.js:10222:16)
            at processQueue (C:/git/angularjs/NSview/NSviewer/Scripts/angular.js:14745:28)
            at C:/git/angularjs/NSview/NSviewer/Scripts/angular.js:14761:27
            at Scope.$eval (C:/git/angularjs/NSview/NSviewer/Scripts/angular.js:15989:28)
            at Scope.$digest (C:/git/angularjs/NSview/NSviewer/Scripts/angular.js:15800:31)
            at Function.$httpBackend.flush (C:/git/angularjs/NSview/NSviewer/Scripts/angular-mocks.js:1543:38)
            at Object.<anonymous> (C:/git/angularjs/NSview/NSviewer/app/tests/testServiceAPI.js:54:26)
        Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
            at C:/git/angularjs/NSview/NSviewer/Scripts/angular.js:68:12
            at beginPhase (C:/git/angularjs/NSview/NSviewer/Scripts/angular.js:16346:15)
            at Scope.$digest (C:/git/angularjs/NSview/NSviewer/Scripts/angular.js:15780:9)
            at Function.$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation (C:/git/angularjs/NSview/NSviewer/Scripts/angular-mocks.js:1575:38)
```

EDIT: 
Added:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET(jsonLayer0);
```

Added:
Full stack trace

Comment: can you post the full stack trace of error.

Answer (score 2):

It is required to tell `$httpBackend` to expect a GET request.

Try the following code

```
it('should fetch first layer', function () {
    $httpBackend.expectGET(jsonLayer0);
    var controller = createController();
    $rootScope.getFirstLayer();
    $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, but added it, and I still get the same error! :/

Comment: @ganjan Remove $httpBackend.expectGET(jsonLayer0); from beforeEach function and add it to test case only.